# I can't pass data from a child component to another child component. Any toughts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to pass data from A component to the B via services, subject and subscribe. In the first component there are many input values im passing to the service and then i wanted to subsrcibe to the services getData() function to get respond.The input values have to appear on a html table of the B component.
A component's ts file: updating senddata2

```
sendData(): void {
    this.receiptdataService.sendData2(this.cusName, this.buyDate, this.realDate, this.product, this.cusComment, this.prodPrice);
    console.log(this.receiptdataService.receipts)
}
```

A component's HTML:here im calling inputdata function

```
<button (click)="inputData()" [disabled]="!receiptform.valid" type="submit" class=" btn btn-outline-success">Mentés</button>
```

service:

```
    receipts =[
      {cusName:"Barka",buyDate:"2019-01-23",realDate:"2020-12-21",product:"macska",cusComment:"NEm tetszik",prodPrice:233423}
    ]
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendData2(name:string, date:string,date2:string,item:string,comment:string,price:number) {
       this.subject.next({ cusName:name ,buyDate:date,realDate:date2,product:item,cusComment:comment,prodPrice:price});
    }

getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

B comonent's ts file. Here im doing subscription to the getData()

```
  subscription: Subscription;
  receipt:any[]=[]
  constructor(private router: Router,private receiptdataService: ReceiptdataService) { 

  // subscribe to create component data
  this.subscription = this.receiptdataService.getData().subscribe(res => {
    if (res) {
      console.log(res)
        this.receipt.push(res);
    }
   });
  }
```

the B component's html file: i want here to put table elements in.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Vásárló neve</th>
        <th>Kiállítás dátuma</th>
        <th>Esedékesség dátuma</th>
        <th>Tétel neve</th>
        <th>Komment</th>
        <th>Ár</th>
   <tr>
    <tr >
        <td *ngFor="let items of receipt">{{items}}</td>
    </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Could you try this bind solution I gave in the previous question?

Comment: Is there really nothing in the logs? Not even your `console.log(this.receiptdataService.receipts)`? General thought is that you should try to avoid executing logic within the constructor of your components and better place it in `ngOnInit` to stay within the "normal" angular life cycle hooks

Comment: Yes i tried.The whole is uptated. @NarenMurali

Comment: In your code for component A, you define method `sendData()`, but `onclick` handler calls `inputData()` -- could this be the reason of your troubles?

Comment: Keep in mind you are using a Subject so it will notify only of new emissions but not of the previous ones. If your component subscribes to the Subject.asObservable() after subject has already been updated, your component would not receive any data. If that is the case you can use BehaviorSubject() which keeps one previous emission, or ReplaySubject() if you need more than one previous emission